# Polymorphic (new) field changing value in base class

Tags: c#, polymorphism, derived-class, base-class

Important: I cannot use properties, I need to serialize field. C# 6.0

The stuff is simple, field is defined in base class and another class inherits this field from base class. Field in subclass changes it type - important that the type is always enum, but serialization depends on enum type so it must be strongly typed. Then changing value in base class expects same change in subclass by calling some method in subclass. It is not happening, becouse field is marked as new, so it has it own memory allocation. How to change this behaviour, without telling subclass to clone value?

```
enum Foo { };
enum Bar { };

abstract class Base
{
    protected Foo someEnum;

    public void Load(int someVal)
    {
        someEnum = (Foo)someVal;
    }
}

class Child : Base
{
    public new Bar someEnum;
}

class Program
{
    void Main()
    {
        var c = new Child();
        c.Load(7);

        Assert((int)c.someEnum == 7);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get pretty close using Generics.
Starting with c# 7.3 you can use a generic constraint for `Enum` - so you can do something like this:

```
abstract class Base {
    public abstract void Load(int someVal);
}

class Base<T> : Base
    where T : Enum
{
    protected T someEnum;

    public override void Load(int someVal)
    {
        someEnum = (T)someVal;
    }
}

class FooWrapper : Base<Foo> {/* implementation */}

class BarWrapper : Base<Bar> {/* implementation */}
```

Now `FooWrapper` and `BarWrapper` are siblings, so they don't inherit eachother, but they both inherit the `Base<T>` class and that inherits the `Base` class`

Comment: Thanks for this reply, I didn't mention that c# version 6 is only supported, sorry about that, I have already edited the post

Comment: Ok tested in c#6, works well for Enum constrain, im not sure why but CLR allows it